# KendoUI Grid - How to declaratively set MVVM data column template to external template?

Tags: kendo-ui

I am struggling with declarative setting grid column to a external template

Here's my template

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="someTemplate">
    <div>
        <label> ${firstName}</label>  
        <label>${lastName}</label>
    </div>
</script>
```

and here's the grid declaration

```
<div data-role="grid" data-bind="source: people" data-columns='[
    {"field": "firstName",
     "title": "Full Name",
     "template": "kendo.template($("#someTemplate"))"
    }
]'></div>
```

And here's JS Fiddle reproducing my problem:
[JSFiddle repro](http://jsfiddle.net/malovicn/bSGdW/8/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of expirements I've found out that ....

template: kendo.template($("\\#check-results-template").html())

so just watch out the '#' wherever use kendo things  !!

Comment: You shouldn't need to escape the pound sign. I think you are experiencing that because you have the line wrapped in quotes.  "template": "kendo.template($("#someTemplate"))" should be  template: kendo.template($("#someTemplate")) - see answer from @Samuel Caillerie

Answer (score 8):

You have 2 mistakes in your code :

1. you have to make your template from the html of the script element
2. you have to call directly `kendo.template(...)` as it is a function and not between quotes.

This gives such code :

```
"template": kendo.template($("#someTemplate").html())
```

See this jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bSGdW/9/